# Determine number of files in directory with only looking at `ls -ald`

Tags: ls

I have a directory with lots of files.

How can I find out by the size of meta data reported by ls

```
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data www-data 1017M Aug  8 10:44 cookies_
```

How many files are in the directory.

I do not want to count them  (even in [Determining number of files in a directory without counting them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67654/determining-number-of-files-in-a-directory-without-counting-them) there are counting them)

Comment: P.S. If I’m not mistaken, `ls -ald` is equivalent to `ls -ld` — the `d` option makes the `a` option irrelevant.

Comment: @Scott I think you're mistaken

Comment: @jrw32982: Do you have any evidence to support your thought?

Comment: @Scott `man ls`
-a, --all: do not ignore entries starting with .
-d, --directory: list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

Comment: @jrw32982: That supports my point.  `-d` means list directory entries instead of contents, or, somewhat more clearly, “list directories themselves, not their contents” [(see `ls(1)` **here**)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) — in short, ***don’t list directory contents***, further discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186466/23408) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215566/23408).  `-a` and `-A` affect *which* entries are listed (and which are not) when listing a directory’s contents — which *doesn’t happen* when you specify `-d`, so `-a` and `-A` are moot.

Comment: @Scott I see what you're saying.  I don't know where the original command `ls -ald` came from, but you're right that when you use `-d` it doesn't seem to help (or hurt) to use `-a`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can’t, for a number of reasons.

The first is that a directory’s size grows, but it doesn’t shrink (on most file systems anyway). Try this:

```
mkdir testdir && cd testdir
touch {1..100000}
rm {1..100000}
ls -ld ../testdir
```

This will produce a fairly large directory (nothing like yours admittedly, but that’s irrelevant here) containing no files...

The second is that in most cases, file records inside a directory entry are variable in length, depending on the file’s name. See for example the [ext4 disk layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Directory_Entries).

The third is that the directory might not even be linear, which complicates matters further.

The fourth is that a directory’s size is a multiple of the block size, so a directory with one file and a directory with twenty will usually have the same size.

Comment: Can the second and third reason be mitigated if you know approximately the size of the filename, and the structure of the directory? (Not sure what you mean by _linear_ here)

Comment: @pipe if all the files have names with similar lengths, you can use that to get an approximate upper bound to the number of files in the directory — if your file names occupy 12 bytes on average, an ext4 directory will use 20 bytes on average per entry (plus checksum blocks). By non-linear, I mean that there might be holes (in some file systems), or even tree structures.